# How to acces shared object and display on facebook/Twitter URL Link AS3

Tags: android, facebook, actionscript-3, air, shared-objects

Hey everyone so I was wondering if there is a easy method of doing this or if it can even be done without an ANE  Native Extension. I picked up some code from around here and in my Flash CS6 Android AIR Application using AS3 I created two buttons on the stage one for Facebook and the other for Twitter. When the user clicks on the buttons they are redirected to the URL's and are able to post the link that I give in the vars like so:

```
    //Share button event listener
        menuEnd.share_Facebook.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, shareFacebook);
        menuEnd.share_Twitter.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, shareTwitter);


    private function shareTwitter(e:MouseEvent):void 
    {
        var varsShare:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
        varsShare.u = 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=air.bunnyRunner';
        varsShare.t = 'Jumpy Bunny';

        var urlTwitterShare:URLRequest = new URLRequest('http://twitter.com/home?status= Jumpy Bunny by Fitchett Productions: ');
        urlTwitterShare.data = varsShare;
        urlTwitterShare.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;

        navigateToURL(urlTwitterShare, '_blank');

    }

    private function shareFacebook(evt:MouseEvent):void
    {
        var varsShare:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
        varsShare.u = 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=air.bunnyRunner';
        varsShare.t = 'Jumpy Bunny';

        var urlFacebookShare:URLRequest = new URLRequest('http://m.facebook.com/sharer.php');
        urlFacebookShare.data = varsShare;
        urlFacebookShare.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;

        navigateToURL(urlFacebookShare, '_blank');
    }
```

So now I was wondering since I have sharedObject data in my game is there anyway to get that shared.data and display it on facebook when the user clicks the button it shares the data to facebook and they can post their highscore?

Thanks guys any help is appreciated.